# Jenkins download dependencies on each build

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I have installed Jenkins on local server and configured it for Android project.

Now when I run build, instead of loading jars from cacher `user/.gradle` it starts downloading gradle plugin and other dependencies. I have gradle 3.0 installed and I have same version in gradle wrapper. Also, I have set `GRADLE_USER_HOME` system variable. I am using Jenkins for the first time. How can I configure it to load dependencies from **gradle** **cache**?